# Issues with flushing cout after getting file data

Tags: c++, file, segmentation-fault, buffer, ifstream

I am trying to write an implementation of rc4. I am reading in plaintext from a file using an ifstream. I noticed that it wasn't outputting at the end of the file, so I tried the various ways of explicitly clearing the buffers. No matter which way (using an endl, appending \n, calling cout.flush()) I try to flush the buffer, I get a segfault. As a sanity check, I replaced my code with an example from the web, which I also tested separately. It works if I put it in its own file and compile it (e.g., it prints out the contents of the file, doesn't segfault, and doesn't require any calls to flush() or endl to do so), but not in my code.

Here is the offending bit of code (which works fine outside of my code; its copied pretty much directly from cplusplus.com)

```
 ifstream is;
 is.open("plain");
 char c;
 while (is.good())     // loop while extraction from file is possible
 {
     c = is.get();       // get character from file
     if (is.good())
         cout << c;
//       cout.flush();
 }
 is.close();           // close file*/
```

Here is the full code: (warning, lots of commented out code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
static char s[256], k[256];
//static char *i, *j;
void swap(int m, int n, char t[256]){
        char tmp = t[m];
        t[m] = t[n];
        t[n] = tmp;
}

char getByte(){
        static char i(0), j(0);
        i = (i+1)%256;
        j = (j + s[i])%256;
        swap(i, j, s);
        return s[(s[i]+s[j]) % 256];
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
        /*string key = argv[1];*/
        if(argc < 4){
                cout << "Usage: \n rc4 keyfile plaintextfile outputfile" << endl;
                return -1;
        }
        string key;
        ifstream keyfile (argv[1]);
        keyfile >> k;
        cout << "Key = " << k << endl;
        keyfile.close();
        /*ifstream plaintextf;
        plaintextf.open(argv[2]);*/

        ofstream ciphertextf (argv[3]);

        for(int q = 0; q < 256; q++){
                s[q] = q;
        }
        int i, j;
        for(int m = 0; m < 256; m++){
                j = (j + s[m] + k[m % sizeof(k)])%256;
                swap(m, j, s);
        }
//      vector<char> bytes(plaintext.begin(), plaintext.end());
//      bytes.push_back('\0');
//      vector<char>::iterator it = bytes.begin();
/*      char pt;
        while(plaintextf.good()){
                pt = plaintextf.get();
                if(plaintextf.good()){
                        cout << pt;

                      ciphertextf <<(char) (pt ^ getByte());
                }

        } */
        ifstream is;
        is.open("plain");
        char c;
         while (is.good())     // loop while extraction from file is possible
         {
            c = is.get();       // get character from file
            if (is.good())
              cout << c;
//              cout.flush();
         }
  is.close();           // close file*/

/*//    plaintextf.close();
        ciphertextf.close();
        keyfile.close();
        */
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're probably inserting a raw `'\0'` character into the stream. Cast the `char` to an `int` before inserting and see if that works.

Comment: Because that did not help... I'm kinda at a loss here.

Comment: Have you run your program in a debugger? It will help you pinpoint the location of the crash and also let you examine variables to help you figure out what might be wrong.

Comment: I have looked at it in a debugger. It depends on which code is commented out, but typically it segfaults whenever I attempt to flush cout (by using an endl or flush()), or at the end of execution (even after the return statement). So in the first bit of code above, it segfaults on "cout.flush();" or if I add an endl to "cout << c". In either case, none of the file gets printed before it segfaults.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, I think the second call to is.good() [ as in if(is.good()) ], would prevent the very last character of the file from being copied.

Comment: I was wondering why the example had that in it - wouldn't it not matter if the file is good or not, as I'd already stored it in c using get()?

Comment: The call to is.get() could fail, and that's why they added the is.good() test.  However, good() is also false after EOF.  So in normal, healthy operation good() would return false for the last character simply because EOF was reached.
It would probably be best to replace the second good() test with fail(), since fail() is not affected by EOF.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That doesn't seem to be related to my problem, but it will probably help once I get this stream nonsense figured out.

Comment: How long is the key length?  256 chars or 255?  Do you need to add an additional byte to char k[256] to hold the NULL that gets added by operator>> ?  In any case, the construction of the file could certainly cause this buffer to be written past its bounds.  Perhaps you need to use the binary read functions instead of the text extract operator, or use the width modifier.